# How to get notified when child is added in Firebase adapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

So I was working on a project, something like social network and I came across the problem.
I have finished loading the list of data with Firebase UI component RecyclerView Adapter, it worked. For this I was using the docs, since I am new to Firebase. But every time someone adds a new post the database automatically refreshes itself and goes back to top. 
Any idea if I could make the firebase adapter to notify me when the data changes? I am not so good with the adapter so I decided not to use custom, but to use already made adapter.
I am using Kotlin language.

Thank You!!

Comment: Share with us what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried using the custom array adapter, but no luck. I couldn't manage to make it. Now I have added onChildChangedListener. And I neeed to be notified when I am not at the top of the list